# How to install specific .egg pieces with easy_install

Tags: easy-install, egg, python-2.5, zodb

I am trying to install ZODB on a new machine.  I would like to match the same installation I have on another machine (the newest ZODB does not install correctly with easy_install).  I have the easy-install.pth from the original that I would like to install on the new machine:

```
import sys; sys.__plen = len(sys.path)
./zodb3-3.10.0b1-py2.5-win32.egg
./zope.interface-3.8.0-py2.5-win32.egg
./zope.event-3.5.1-py2.5.egg
./zdaemon-2.0.4-py2.5.egg
./zconfig-2.9.0-py2.5.egg
./zc.lockfile-1.0.0-py2.5.egg
./transaction-1.1.1-py2.5.egg
import sys; new=sys.path[sys.__plen:]; del sys.path[sys.__plen:]; p=getattr(sys,'__egginsert',0); sys.path[p:p]=new; sys.__egginsert = p+len(new)
```

Is there a way install these exact files on the new machine?  I tried copying the folders onto the new machine, but python does not see the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just copying over the .egg folders over to the new machine as well as the easy-install.pth (which I renamed to zodb.pth) and everything worked great.  Not perfect, but exactly what I was looking to do.

Answer (score 1):

pip supports a manifest or you can use zc.buildout.  pip may be the least friction if you are comfortable with easy_install.